# Undelete Fails on Account - Any other way to restore contacts on it?

Tags: undelete

Someone deleted an account that was a catchall account and had 10K+ Contacts in it.

When I try to undelete I get the error:"Task(id: 00T1500001lDCKG) cannot include a mix of contacts and a lead."

I can query the undeleted task record, but only see an associated contact.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  When I try to undelete the contacts I am told they are "Not in the Recycle Bin".

Any ideas on how to recover these contacts?

Thanks,
Cole

Comment: Did you have any backups set for your org where you can grab the values from the day previous the deletion that you can restore from?

Comment: Yes, we have dbamp and I can use that data to import via API as new data.  Was trying to avoid that, but looks like that's where I'm at.

Answer (score 2):

This solution will cost you money and it is not cheap, but if you file a Case with Salesforce right away, there's a good chance they can restore the data for you. If you do not have a back-up of your data, with the error message you are receiving, this may be the only way of recovering the lost contacts. It will be up to you to decide the value of the information when deciding whether or not to pursue this approach.

For future reference, I recommend you consider implementing a minimum best practice of exporting your basic data to CSV files on a regularly scheduled basis using the tools found in Setup that can automate the process for you. Even better would be to implement a more extensive back-up program using one of the App Exchange products like Spanning Backup or one of several other solutions. Again, it all depends on how much you value your data.

This is also a good time to review all profile permissions for delete privileges on Accounts and other objects in your org. Use this as a "wake up call" and "learning experience". You can probably be thankful you've only lost 10k contacts and not more. Think about the impact to your company if a malicious user deleted 100 of your most important accounts! This is your chance to create a plan for both preventing and recovering from that kind of catastrophe.

Comment: We have dbamp, so I can recover the contacts and related objects, but it's going to require importing them as new objects and reconnecting them to other objects, it will be tedious, but looks like that's what needs to happen.

Agree on all other points.